# object has no attribute 'material'

Tags: python, scripting

I am using blender 3.2, am trying to execute the below steps using python script

s1) Import Rigged avatar (.glb) into Blender

s2) Select the mesh of upper human body

s3) Go to shade editor, delete existing material and add new material

s4) @shade editor, select "Principled BSDF" and use Hot key ctrl + shift + t to upload the image
of texture (Node wrangler is already enabled)

s5) Adjust the scale parameters at the Mapping node

s6)Export the updated avatar in same glb format

I generated the below script for the above steps:

```
import bpy
import functools

threeD_viewport = None
bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath="C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\stage\\STAGEGLB3.glb", files=[{"name":"STAGEGLB3.glb", 
      "name":"STAGEGLB3.glb"}], loglevel=50)
      
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas: 
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for space in area.spaces: 
            if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                threeD_viewport = space

threeD_viewport.shading.type = 'MATERIAL'
threeD_viewport.material.new()
bpy.ops.node.select(deselect_all=True, location=(420, 240))
bpy.ops.node.nw_add_textures_for_principled(filepath="C:\\Users\\brown_color.jpg", directory="C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\", files=[{"name":"brown_color.jpg", "name":"brown_color.jpg"}], relative_path=True)
bpy.data.materials["Material.003"].node_tree.nodes["Mapping"].inputs[3].default_value[0] = 5
bpy.data.materials["Material.003"].node_tree.nodes["Mapping"].inputs[3].default_value[1] = 5
bpy.context.space_data.shading.type = 'MATERIAL'
bpy.context.space_data.system_bookmarks_active = 3
bpy.context.space_data.system_bookmarks_active = 1
bpy.context.space_data.system_bookmarks_active = 1
bpy.context.space_data.params.filename = "STAGEGLB4.glb"
```

The error am getting is at line 11

**Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\Text", line 18, in 
AttributeError: 'SpaceView3D' object has no attribute 'material'**

@`marty-fouts` can u pls help us in this regard

Thanks
vij

Comment: `nw_xxxx` ops are from the Node Wrangler addon. Is it installed/activated?

Comment: Node Wrangler addon is activated before generating the python script

Answer (score 0):

After long R&D able to figure out the solution:

FYI: ensure materials of the mesh are deleted manually in shading editor before executing the script

```
import bpy 
import os

bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath="C:\\Users\\STAGEGLB42.glb", import_pack_images=True,import_shading='NORMALS', loglevel=50)

material_basic= bpy.data.materials.new(name="Basic")

material_basic.use_nodes=True

bpy.context.object.active_material=material_basic

selectmesh=bpy.data.objects['stage1']

selectmesh.data.materials.append(material_basic)

bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(filepath="d://assa1.glb", export_format='GLB', 
export_image_format='AUTO', export_materials='EXPORT')
```